Slow wifi on Ubuntu 24.04 compared to Windows 11
I'm trying to replace Windows with Ubuntu 24.04. Currently I use dual boot. I'm experiencing very slow internet speed on Ubuntu compared to Windows 11.
Output of lshw :
*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
                version: 31
                serial: d0:c5:d3:2f:6d:13
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=6.8.0-49-Wgeneric firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.1.198 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:135 memory:ef200000-ef3fffff


sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off && sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and see if it is any better

Thank you very much for your help. Since I'm not very familiar with the use of the terminal so I'm not sure how to use the commands you listed. Are these two separate commands like: sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off    and  sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf. I used them in to terminal but nothing happened. Sorry for the troible but I am a total begginer here.

It was intended to be run as one long command

Sorry for misunderstanding. I tried the command this time but there's no improvement. The speed is about the same. Is there anything else I can try?

Are you using a mesh network?

Don't know what that is, so probably not :-) I have two laptops (one is older) and both have the same problem with slow WiFi. I Both connect to internet through the same router via Wifi.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit to include wireless script results

Thank you for the instruction. How can I add the results of the wireless script here? The commet field only alows  a short messages so the script results are to big to fit into the comment.

You could press y when asked to upload results and then just add the URL to the results

I hope this is OK: https://termbin.com/4ycm

Definitely try sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off then reboot

Thank you for your persistence. I tried both commands but with not much improvement. The internet speed on Ubuntu is still about factor 5 slower than on Windows :-(

Sounds like gedit is not installed. You can try sudo nano /etc/default/grub .... This always been weird with Ubuntu. Sometimes gedit is installed. Sometimes not. If sudo nano doesn't work I would install gedit. sudo apt-get install gedit .... Then you can run the sudo gedit command. Cheers

Thank you for your help! I've managed to execute the commands but It didn't improve WiFi speed.

I'm using 'legacy' boot om my Dell 1545 and this fixed my slow boot issue. It may or may not work for you. In /etc/default/grub edit the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" entry:
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub Edit: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="tsc=unstable" Save the file, then sudo update-grub Reboot. If it doesn't work, you can just remove the added text then sudo update-grub and Reboot. Cheers

Thank you for your advice. When putting the command: sudo gedit /etc/default/grub in a terminal, I get an error: sudo: gedit: command not found. What am I doing wrong?

It's likely the gedit command is wrong. Use sudo nano etc/default/grub - 24.04 replaced 'Gedit' text editor with the new 'Nano' text editor. Sorry about that.

Thank you very much for your help. To be honest though, I don't know what to do. Looks like I don't have enough knowledge about Ubuntu to work this out anyway. It's kind of complicated and It takes me too much time just to get the basics stuff right. Back to Windows I guess :-(  Thanks again!
